# Python Requests Digest Authorization

Tags: python, nginx, python-requests

Hi I am working on a simple program to get a token-id from a router using REST API. The problem that I am facing, is that I do not see the Authorization headers when I use HTTPDigestAuth. When I use the Google App POSTMAN, I can see the headers and it work. What I am missing in my code?

My code:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth, HTTPDigestAuth

user = 'pod1u1'
passwd = 'pass'

url = 'https://10.0.236.188/api/v1/auth/token-services'
auth = HTTPDigestAuth(user, passwd)
r = requests.post(url, auth=auth, verify=False)
print 'Request headers:', r.request.headers
print 'Status Code: ', r.status_code
print 'response Headers: ', r.headers

print '######################################'

auth = HTTPBasicAuth(user, passwd)
r = requests.post(url, auth=auth, verify=False)
print 'Request headers:', r.request.headers
print 'Status Code: ', r.status_code
print 'response Headers: ', r.headers
```

Shell commands w/ output:

My script --

```
$python digest.py 
Request headers: CaseInsensitiveDict({'Content-Length': '0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,     deflate, compress', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.2.0 CPython/2.7.5 Darwin/13.0.0'})
Status Code:  401
response Headers:  CaseInsensitiveDict({'date': 'Tue, 14 Jan 2014 00:28:27 GMT', 'content-length': '83', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'server': 'nginx/1.4.2'})
######################################
Request headers: CaseInsensitiveDict({'Accept': '*/*', 'Content-Length': '0', 'Accept-    Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, compress', 'Authorization': u'Basic cG9kMXUxOkMxc2NvTDF2Mw==', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.2.0 CPython/2.7.5 Darwin/13.0.0'})
Status Code:  401
response Headers:  CaseInsensitiveDict({'date': 'Tue, 14 Jan 2014 00:28:27 GMT', 'content-length': '448', 'content-type': 'text/html', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'server': 'nginx/1.4.2'})
```

POSTMAN

```
POST /api/v1/auth/token-services HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.0.236.188
Authorization: Digest username="pod1u1", realm="pod1u1@ecatsrtpdmz.cisco.com", nonce="",     uri="/api/v1/auth/token-services", response="08ac88b7f5e0533986e9fc974f132258", opaque=""
Cache-Control: no-cache


{
    "kind": "object#auth-token",
    "expiry-time": "Tue Jan 14 00:09:27 2014",
    "token-id": "Vj7mYUMTrsuljaiXEPoNJNiXLzf8UeDsRnEgh3DvQcU=",
    "link": "https://10.0.236.188/api/v1/auth/token-services/9552418862"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a POST, so intuitively, you need to pass 'params' argument to requests.post method

You can use a sniffer to see exactly what POSTMAN send to the url and do the same...

Just for info, I did a requests.get with digest credentials (on another url), it worked and I saw auth headers.

Maybe you could first start with a GET to create a "session" then do your POST, just a guess :)

[ADDED]

I would also try to use "raw" headers as a workaround :

```
[...]
headers = {
    "Host": "10.0.236.188",
    "Authorization": '''Digest username="pod1u1", realm="pod1u1@ecatsrtpdmz.cisco.com", nonce="",     uri="/api/v1/auth/token-services", response="08ac88b7f5e0533986e9fc974f132258", opaque=""''',
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
}
r = requests.post(url, auth=auth, headers=headers, verify=False)
```

[/ADDED]

Comment: That is the Response from the POSTMAN request. The router in question is a Cisco brand and this format is also detailed in the documentation there.

Comment: @selllikesybok : changed my answer accordingly... did you try doing a GET first or use a sniffer ?

Comment: @selllikesybok : and sth else, url is https, why not using verify=True ? hum, no, this should not change anything for the server side...

Comment: No params needed(http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/routers/csr1000/software/restapi/RESTAPIclient.html). This works with HTTPBasicAuth, but I need AAA and that force me to use HTTPDigestAuth. I use wireshark, but the connection is https :(. The r.request.headers should show me the Authorization header but it is not.

Comment: Can you print `r.history` and show me what the output is for the Digest Auth case?

Comment: Looks like it is empty. This is how I print it; print "Request History: ", r.history ----> Request History:  []

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is in the server side: Lukasa @ GitHUB help me. "That doesn't look like a service that requires Digest Auth. If Digest Auth is required, the 401 should contain a header like this: WWW-Authenticate: Digest qop="auth". This does not. Instead, you're being returned a JSON body that contains an error message.
Digest Auth should not send headers on the initial message, because the server needs to inform you how to generate the digest. I invite you to open up the section of code that generates the digest. We require the realm, nonce and qop from the server before we can correctly generate the header."